# How to fail the container if the task fails, always return success

Tags: powershell, ssis

[image: Package]

i have two Execute process task it executes the PS script. It always returns success even-though if the script fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: I just changed the parallel container property]

ForceExecutionResult is None

Now the container will fail if the task inside the container fails.